# difference between rad masked text input and radmasked text box?

Tags: text

well i tried their web site also,they are only providing details regarding there use i mean about controls.
what is the exact difference between both of the above mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

This Telerik's forum post answers, I think: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/maskedtextbox/is-it-possible-to-use-a-radmaskedtextinput-as-a-multiline-text-area.aspx#1863327

> The RadMaskedInput controls don't support a "no-mask" scenarios at
>   the moment...
>
> This is why ... it would be best to take
>   advantage of the RadMaskedTextBox control. It has a property MaskType,
>   which you can set to None. Also in order to make it multi-line, you
>   need to apply a custom style to its ExtendedTextBox element and set
>   its AcceptsReturn property to True.